# How to fit a large image in image view without stretching the image?

Tags: iphone

I am using a image view and its size is (320X480). i want to fit a image which size is (800X600) in image view without stretching the image. i tried to make the image 320X480 but its quality becomes poor. Thanks for any solution.

Answer (score 0):

320x240 would be the same aspect ratio. Notice, 800/600 = 4/3 and 320/240 = 4/3.

Also, in the future a tool like ImageMagick can allow you to resize an image to fit within some bounding box while maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: thanks Bobby Shaftoe for quick reply

i know. how to resize the image but i need the image in 320X480 size.

Comment: @Pankaj Chauhan, I don't know what you mean. You can resize the image to 320x240 and it will fit and preserve the aspect ratio. The short and long answer is you can't resize the image to 320x480 and not have it look bad. What you would doing is skewing it. You can make the image smaller and then use whitespace. Alternatively, if you have a vector version of the image then you can do some more sophisticated manipulating.